# Нужно поднять блок с картинками CSS,HTML,Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

хочу поднять блок с картинками регистрации и логина на 50 пикселей в верх. но при использовании margin-top:50px; не работает почему хз. Блок который нужно поднять носит id Acount и в нем находиться

с id Buttons в них находяться изображения которое нужно поднять

wrapper.html

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap');


body {
 background-color: #6666D0;
 font-family: "Lato" ;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #555;

 -webkit-font-soothing: antialiased;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

 margin-top: 70px;

}



h2,h4,h5,h6{
 font-family: "Lato";
 font-weight: 300;
 color:#333;
}

h3{
 font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;

}

h1{
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
 color:#333;
}


p{
 line-height: 28px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.centered{
 text-align: center;
}

a{
 font-family: "Oswald";
 font-size: 30px;
}

a:hover , a:focus{
 color:#0000A9;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: 0;
}

hr {
 height: 1px;
 border: 0;
 border-top:1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 1em 0;
 padding:0;
}


li {
 margin-top:60px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.li:active, .li:hover{
 background-color: #0000A9 ;
}
.navbar{
 margin-top: -80px;
 font-weight:800;
 font-size:14px;
 padding-top:15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar-inverse{
 padding-left: 400px;
 background:#000047;
 border-color: #000031;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand{
 color: #999 ;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 22px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#headrwrap{

 margin: 300px ;

}

#Buttons{
 margin-left: 60px
}

.form-control{
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius:4px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075) inset;
 color: #555 ;
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 34px;
 line-height: 1.42857;
 padding: 6px 12px;
 width: 50%;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 25%;
}



.EnterText{
 margin-left: 150px;
}

.close{
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}



#next-block{
 width: 120px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-left: 60px;
 display:inline-block;

}

#tryFlex{
 display: block;


}


.wrapper, .other {
 display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 80%;
}

.block {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block div {
 flex-basis: 25%;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: #ff9700;
}

.other {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 18%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: purple;
}

#Buttons{
 position:absolute;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#Acount{
 position:relative;
 width:500px;
 height:300px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#columLogo{
 position: relative;
 height: 20%;
 width: 20%;
}
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="witdh=device, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Rapter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/main.js">
    
    
    
      </head>
      <body>
    
    
    <!-- Шапка -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
          <div>
            <div>
    
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
                <a href="https://google.com"><img  src="1px/logo.png" ></a>
    
          </div>
        </div>
    
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
    
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    
    
              <li class="li"><a id="a" href="/news/">Главная</a></li>
              <li class="li"><a id="a" href="/shop/">Игры</a></li>
              <li class="li"><a id="a" href="/projects/">Проекты</a></li>
              <li class="li"><a id="a" href="/aboutUs">О нас</a></li>
    
              <div class="container" id="Acount">
                 <li class="container" id="Buttons">
                   <a href="#"> <img src="1px/enter.png" > </a>
                   <a href="#"> <img src="1px/reg.png"> </a>
                 </li>
               </div>
    
    
            </ul>
    
    
            </ul>
    
            </div>
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
```

Comment: А разве margin-top: 50px не должен опустить блок на 50 пикселей?

Comment: Думаю, если бы вы смогли выложили полный код - вам непременно кто-нибудь оказал бы помощь, а так очень трудно, если вроде бы очевидные вещи у вас не работают и полного кода нет